# Center on viewport - a fixed height a width div VERTICALLY using either js or CSS method

Tags: jquery, css, vertical-alignment

I have a div with several images inside, and I would like to center this vertically. I can give a specific width and height do the div. No prob. I also accept js if I must to. I'm just wondering, from the MAZE of those examples, can I have a simple one.

The div as width of 600 and height of 500.

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy peasy. Say your div has `id="myDiv"`. Then...

```
#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px; // half the height of #myDiv
}
```

...will center the div inside of its offset parent.

[Half-scale demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2gW8r/1/) (so that you don't have to make your window really big to properly see the effect)

Comment: Yup. And the same will fit for the horizontal side. ;) thanks.

Comment: @MEM: it's actually even easier to center a fixed-width `div` horizontally. Just give it `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Handle this problem simply, you can use padding to the div.

Comment: No I can't. :) At least not a fixed value.